# BLE Write Commands (Write Without Response)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In the Bluetooth 4.0-4.2 Specifications Vol 3 Part F, I can find this text:

> Commands and notifications that are received but cannot be processed, due to
>   buffer overflows or other reasons, shall be discarded. Therefore, those PDUs
>   must be considered to be unreliable.

I wonder, who receives? For Write Commands, is it the ATT server that receives from the ATT client, or might it also be the ATT layer of the sender host that receives a request to send a Write Command from the client app that drops the Write Command, i.e. it gets dropped before even being sent out over the air?

Answer (score 1):

The air interface is often limited in the number of packets it can buffer for a Connection Event. Ditto Notification vs Indication in the other direction (server to client)

Comment: Yes the controller has limited space for outgoing packets. So you mean this sentence I reference can also mean the controller who receives an outgoing packet from host (to be sent over the air)?

Comment: Correct. My interpretation of this is that the receiver silently discards packets that overflow its packet buffer. With acknowledged operations this isn't an issue because GATT operations cannot overlap so there is only ever at most one operation outstanding - no possibility of overflowing any buffers.

Answer (score 1):

> "Commands and notifications that are received..."

Commands, for example, Write request that is from Client to Server, so the Server is receiver. The process is that the client send out the write request to server, and when the server receive the write request(lower layer first received) but it find there is no buffer(or other reasons) for this write request and it will discard the write request(higher layer will not receive the write request).

Notifications, instead, from Server to Client, so the Client is receiver. When the client receive the notification but there is no buffer(or other reasons) it will discard the notification.
This is about flow control of communication protocols not just only for Bluetooth. So if you understand flow control you may not have such confusion.

Comment: You only talk about when the ATT server receives the Write Command that it might then drop the packet. But how do you think about what the Bluetooth stack on the client side should do if it receives packets from the client application that are to be sent over the air, faster than it can send out over the air? May it then drop those packets (before even sending out over the air) or not?

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder, who receives? For Write Commands, is it the ATT server that receives from the ATT client,

Yes, it is the ATT server. Both ATT and GATT are not reliable. however the link layer is reliable. I assume the higher layer e.g. the application shall constitute reliability checking.

> or might it also be the ATT layer of the sender host that receives a
>   request to send a Write Command from the client app that drops the
>   Write Command, i.e. it gets dropped before even being sent out over
>   the air?

This is out of spec,I think Bluetooth stack should return corresponding error e.g. "failer" due to no memory.

Comment: So your interpretation is that if an application sends too many Write Commands too quickly, the bluetooth stack should reply "full no buffer space left"?

Comment: The error code is implementation dependent for different stack vendors. However if you call 'writeCharacteristic' too quickly, the return value should not be TRUE.

Comment: I also see  Chris St John 's comment below however I can not comment under his lines due to the lack of reputation numbers.  The local stack, shall not discard any data which come from upper-layers except the L2CAP flush commands(well this is another story), if local stack can not send data to firmware or air it should return error.  Lets back to the original purpose of this topic: the core spec "3.3.2 Sequential Protocol" which contained the words was mainly described the client and server communications mechanisms.